# Stripe and UnionPay support

Tags: stripe-payments

I was looking into Stripe and its support for UnionPay. On the website, we can clearly see logos that indicates support for UnionPay, but I couldn't find anything in API docs.

Was this supported some time ago and is now deprecated?

If not, can someone point me to their docs or better yet, show me an example performing Gateway payment using UnionPay?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, China UnionPay is just a card brand (like Visa, Mastercard, Diner's Club, etc.) and there is nothing specific you need to do in order to process such cards with Stripe.

You should reach out directly to Stripe's support at https://support.stripe.com/email to get more information.

Comment: i have same problem, did u manage to get a reply? Is it because of where your company is located?

Answer (score 1):

Stripe accepts cards with 16 digits ONLY at the moment.

China UnionPay card length is between 16 and 19 digits.

You can find more details about China UnionPay [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170822221741/https://www.discovernetwork.com/downloads/IPP_VAR_Compliance.pdf)